# Reverse Proxy Specific Request

Tags: php, nginx

I have high load website, my system runs out of memory in peak times. I want to split the load so the read operations which happens to be on specific URls move to another server.

I am using nginx and php-fpm, how do I redirect specific URLs to be processed by PHP-fpm on a different server?

This is the blue print of my requirements.

```
location /feed/generate {
  use php-fpm on a different server
}

location / { #all other requests
 use existing php-fpm
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Setup php-fpm on the second server listening on an externally accessible IP (not 127.0.0.1) port 9000.
The IP address should be private (not routed to the internet) and/or configured to only allow connections from trusted hosts (firewall).

```
upstream feed_php_fpm {
    server <other server ip>:9000;
}

upstream local_fpm {
    server 127.0.0.1:9000;
}

location /feed/generate {
    fastcgi_pass feed_php_fpm;
    include fastcgi.conf;
}

location / {
    fastcgi_pass local_fpm;
    include fastcgi.conf;
}
```

*Please understand what you are doing and the implications of php-fpm listening on a network port vs file socket.*